# PhoneGap on iPhone wont load external scripts

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am currently writing a simple application using PhoneGap (iOS) and running it in the simulator.  The problem is that external URLs seem to refuse to load.  For example using a CDN for jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
```

Will not make `$`/`jQuery` available.  The same problem is happening for weinre when trying to use it.  Is there something I need to change to enable this to work?

Comment: Why don't you include it in your app? If there's someone w/o an internet connection all your scripts won't work too. And: did you checked whether Apple blocked the PhoneGap devs from using external scripts in apps? Because they could be a big security flaw.

Comment: Well I used the example above to illustrate the issue rather than the real use case which happens to be an issue with wienre which you cant just embed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you added the domains of the external links to the ExternalHosts entry in PhoneGap.plist ?

There is a fairly new whitelisting system in PhoneGap that is causing a bit of confusion with external links

From  - http://wiki.phonegap.com/ :

"Also, the latest code has the new white-list feature. If you are referencing external hosts, you will have to add the host in PhoneGap.plist under the "ExternalHosts" key. Wildcards are ok. So if you are connecting to "http://phonegap.com", you have to add "phonegap.com" to the list (or use the wildcard "*.phonegap.com" which will match subdomains as well)."

Comment: Perfect.  This has fixed the problem.  I should learn to read :)

Comment: It's not just you if it makes you feel any better. I think it's probably the most frequently asked question on the IRC channel.