# Whitelist external hosts in phonegap for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I need to make AJAX calls to a webpage from my phonegap app.

For Android I needed to add the page in [phonegap.xml](http://markcoleman.tumblr.com/post/12250782308/ios-phonegap-plist-android-phonegap-xml).

For iPhone I also added an [ExternalHosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035701/phonegap-on-iphone-wont-load-external-scripts) in phonegap.plist.

Where do I have to add my webpage for windows phones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitelisting is currently not supported for WP7. See this related question:

[What is the state of whitelisting in phonegap 1.3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899608/what-is-the-state-of-whitelisting-in-phonegap-1-3-0)

However, the WP7 PhoneGap implementation already has a JavaScript shim for XHR requests to files within local storage, so I am assuming that a whitelist is possible and will come in time.

Why not add it to JIRA for PhoneGap (Callback / Cordova!)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB

Comment: You can, if the service you are calling supports JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue on Callback 1.4.1, use this fix to make xhr reqs work:

https://github.com/cordova/cordova-windows-phone/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

There is a work a round for this in my follow up question. [Andrei Schneider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325440/andrei-schneider) wrote a native cross domain call. See:

[Workaround for missing whitelist in phonegap for windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291809/workaround-for-missing-whitelist-in-phonegap-for-windows-phone)