# Check PhoneGap.exec service exists?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am calling my own [phonegap service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291809/workaround-for-missing-whitelist-in-phonegap-for-windows-phone):

```
     PhoneGap.exec(
          success, //success
          fail, //fail
          "Cdc", //service
          "Call", //action
          path //args
     );
```

Since I have this service only on Windows Phone... How do I test if the service exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newer versions of phonegap you can call your plugins using `plugins.cdc.call();`. Now you can easily check if it exists:

```
if ((typeof plugins !== "undefined") && (typeof plugins.cdc !== "undefined"))
{
    // good to go
}
```