# PhoneGap - Call asp.net webservice

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I am new to PhoneGap, i'm trying out the application in VS 2008 in Win 7. Can you guys please let me know how can i call an ASP.NET webservice from PhoneGap app. (please provide an example too)

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't that call be made on the server side?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you are calling an ASP.NET WebService is not really relevant, you use the same technique for calling any HTTP-based service, you need to make a 'web request'. Probably the easiest way to do this is using the jQuery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function. For example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'you/web/service/url',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To make cross domain call in wp7 you need to implement a phone gap command. See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291809/workaround-for-missing-whitelist-in-phonegap-for-windows-phone).

Answer (score 0):

I got this worked by using JSONP. Normal $.ajax call will not make cross domain calls. We can make cross domain calls using JSONP. Thought of sharing it to you guys

Thanks