# WP7 - PhoneGap FileTransfer returns Null error code

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, file-transfer

I'm trying PhoneGap/Cordova 2.1.0 in WP7 for the first time, so I'm new in this.

What I should do is capturing a picture through the camera and uploading it to a server.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>PhoneGap WP7</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() { }

        function capturePhoto() 
        {
            // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image
            navigator.camera.getPicture(
                onPhotoDataSuccess, 
                onFail, 
                { 
                    quality: 50, 
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL 
                }
            );
        }

        function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) 
        {
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey = "file";
            options.fileName = imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

            var params = new Object();

            options.params = params;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageData, "http://mysite.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
        }

        function onFail(message) 
        {
            navigator.notification.alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }


        var win = function(r) 
        {
            navigator.notification.alert(r.responseCode + " - " + r.response + " - " + r.bytesSent);
        }

        var fail = function(error) 
        {
            navigator.notification.alert(eval(error));
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>PhoneGap Photo Demo</h1>
    <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture a Photo</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try this, the upload doesn't work and I get an empty error object:

```
{ "code":null, "source":null, "target":null, "http_status":null }
```

Some notes:

I followed [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291809/workaround-for-missing-whitelist-in-phonegap-for-windows-phone) for missing whitelist in WP7.

The php code is not written by me, I would do it in asp.net, if someone could provide a working example with an asp.net webservice would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT

I debugged FileTransfer class and I get an error in JsonHelper class:

```
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
{
   result = deserializer.ReadObject(mem);
}
```

The error is: InvalidCastException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

Try replacing

```
uploadOptions = JSON.JsonHelper.Deserialize<UploadOptions[]>(options)[0];
```

with the the following

```
options = JSON.JsonHelper.Deserialize<string[]>(options)[0];
uploadOptions = JSON.JsonHelper.Deserialize<UploadOptions>(options);
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER

The easiest way to troubleshot such issues is to add reference to Cordova library source code instead of compiled WP7CordovaClassLib.dll

cordova-2.1.0-incubating-src\cordova-2.1.0\incubator-cordova-wp7\framework\WP7CordovaClassLib.csproj

http://www.apache.org/dist/incubator/cordova/

and then add breakpoint to standalone\cordovalib\Commands\FileTransfer.cs

```
    /// <summary>
    /// sends a file to a server
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="options">Upload options</param>
    public void upload(string options)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("options = " + options);
        options = options.Replace("{}", "null");
```

Sounds complex, but from my experience line by line debugging is the simplest way to understand what particular goes wrong with Apache Cordova in many situations.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I get an error in Deserializing options in JsonHelper. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'll try this asap. For now I solved the problem using the Cordova lib version 1.7.0. I also used PhoneGap Build to create the Android app but it dowsn't work, it seems like it's never initialized. Do you have some ides about this? Thank you very much.