# Cordova/Phonegap 1.6 media Example

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova

i dont want to mention that Phonegap has gone sloppy recently...
but I'm trying to use the [Media example](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html#Media) taken AS IS from their website
using Xcode 4.3..

beside replacing phonegap.js with cordove.js, duh, i got a lot of errors:

```
ERROR: Method 'create:withDict:' not defined in Plugin 'Media'
FAILED pluginJSON = {"className":"Media","methodName":"create","arguments":["Media1","9476cdcf-7f6c-5e05-a022-fa488e8bed40","http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3"]}
Will use resource 'http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3' from the Internet.    
ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3'
ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3'
ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3'
Unable to download audio from: http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3
Failed to initialize AVAudioPlayer: (null)
```

i just used their example as is, and i'd expect it works...

what should i change? is that a xcode issue maybe??

Answer (score 2):

"whitelist rejection"

Basically, you need to add any external URLs you want to access to the "whitelist" (i.e.: the ExternalHosts key in the Cordova.plist file).

See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8045541/878602

...or the PhoneGap Wiki FAQ for iOS:

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/41631150/PhoneGap%20for%20iOS%20FAQ

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me that you can't download the mp3. Can you enter that url in the iphone's safari and download the mp3?

Do you have your own webserver to try maybe? You could see the logs and see if it gets there at all.

BTW I just used the same example yesterday in Android and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you may updating the cordova. They have changed many function names.

For example if you are using the startAudioRecord function in previous versions. Currently they have changed it as startRecord.

Likewise they have changed many internal function names.

Just open your cordova.js.  check appropriate function and function name exists.